# Access UITextField with tag on a static Table

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

So I have a static TableView setup in the interface builder with multiple sections, labels, and text fields.

I'd like to be able to something along the lines of

```
[self.view viewWithTag:kNameTextfield]
```

and get the UITextField with that tag that I've set.

For some reason I cannot access the UITextField and it comes up Nil. I imagine because it's somewhat deeply nested? I thought about creating an Outlet collection of all the text fields and other than iterating through them every single time I need to change something seems like a waste?

What I'm trying to do is on initial load, it populates the values of the textfield by values in a dictionary. So it's useful to be able to target a specific textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through the subviews:

```
for (UIView* viewsLevel1 in [cell.contentView subviews])
{
    for (UIView* viewsLevel2 in viewsLevel1)
    {
        UITextField *textField = [viewsLevel2 viewWithTag:kNameTextField];
    }
}
```

Go as far deep as you need to go